# Why does calling system() without including stdlib.h still work?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, gcc, debian

The only library I've included in my C program is `stdio.h`. Calling `system()` within that very same program works anyway, though Eclipse complains about an `implicit declaration of function ‘system’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`, whatever that means.

However, GCC (the compiler I'm using) seems happy. Would it be that Eclipse is automatically fixing the issue before compilation, or is GCC just kind enough to do that without complaining? I understand nothing of this.

I'm using GNU/Linux Debian 11 (Bullseye) Stable, if that makes any difference.

Comment: `implicit declaration of function ‘system’` : that's the exact reason why it works. Whenever you see this warning, consider it as an error.

Comment: Whenever you see any warning, consider it an error.

Comment: Note that you are still using the library. Not including the h file just means you are not calling the library properly.

Comment: standard C allows any standard library to implicitly include other standard libraries. It is possibly that somewhere in stdio.h there were need to include part of stdlib. It is not portable to assume any indirect inclusion, but it is non-portable to assume there is no additional standard library included (after you use one of them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once upon a time, the rule in C was that if you called a function the compiler had never heard of, it quietly assumed it was an ordinary function returning `int`.

The `system()` function fits that description.

In more recent versions of the C Standard, the "implicit `int`" rule has been removed, and you are required to declare all functions before calling them.  A modern compiler is obliged to issue a diagnostic if you fail to declare a called function.  However, there's nothing keeping the compiler from having the diagnostic be a nonfatal warning, and going on to compile your program anyway, making use of the old assumption.  And in fact, many compilers still do that, perhaps to make it easier to compile old code written under the old rules.

Comment: Everything else here is fine but what you say about the argument list is inaccurate. An implicit declaration gives the function no prototype, and therefore it can subsequently be called with *any number and type* of arguments, whether or not this is consistent with the first use. Moreover, all the arguments are subject to "argument promotion" just like the anonymous arguments to a variadic function.

Comment: @zwol Good points.  I took that paragraph back out.